# How to force Java dynamic method call binding

Tags: java, dynamic, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Overload method with inherited interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601365/java-overload-method-with-inherited-interface)

I'm not positive my title is correct, but I'm sure I'll be corrected if it's not.

I'm trying to overload the helpIt method like so:

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal{}

class Foo implements AnimalHelper
{
  @Override
  public void helpAnAnimal( Animal a )
  { 
    helpIt( a );
  }

  private void helpIt( Dog d )
  {}

  private void helpIt( Animal a )
  {}
}
```

The problem is this never calls the helpIt( Dog d ) method, even when the animal is a Dog.
I used this approach because the class Foo overrides the AnimalHelper's helpAnAnimal method.

Am i missing something here?  I would hope i don't have to check instanceof and then cast it.
I believe this worked out of the box in .Net, but that memory is a bit faded and possibly incorrect.

Comment: At compile time, Java sees the Dog as an Animal (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601365/java-overload-method-with-inherited-interface).

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110631/java-overloading-and-inheritance-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `helpIt()` method an overridable instance method of `Animal`:

```
class Foo implements AnimalHelper {
    @Override
    helpAnAnimal(Animal a) { 
        a.helpIt();
    }
}
```

Or use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
public interface AnimalVisitor {
    void visitDog(Dog d);
    void visitOther(Animal a);
}

public class Animal {
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.acceptOther(this);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.acceptDog(this);
    }
}

class Foo implements AnimalHelper {
    @Override
    helpAnAnimal(Animal a) { 
        a.accept(new AnimalVisitor() {
            public void visitDog(Dog d) {
                helpIt(d);
            }
            public void visitOther(Animal a) {
                helpIt(a);
            }
        });
    }

    private void helpIt(Dog d) {
    }

    private void helpIt(Animal a) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I never used it before, but I like the visitor pattern because it keeps the functionality where I want it and allows for multiple implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as Java sees them all as Animals at compile time.

What you can do is add the algorithms that are Animal / Dog specific to the actual Dog class, for example:

```
class Animal {

    protected boolean hasRabies() {
        return animal.name.equals("Tim");
    }
}

class Dog {

    @Override
    protected boolean hasRabies() {
        return false; // Apparently dogs can't have rabies?
    }
}
```

Then you can call these specific methods in the helpAnimal:

```
private void helpIt(Animal a) {
    if (a.hasRabies()) {
        a.setTreats(4000);
    } else {
        a.setTreats(3000);
    }
}
```

I am not a veterinarian.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the helpIt(Dog d) from a method of the same class?

Note, you have used private for the methods and you will not be able to use these methods outside this class.

Answer (score 0):

A few of things here:

- Java definitely won't call the `helpIt(Dog d)` method because the variable `a` is of type `Animal`. You'll have to manually check and call the correct method. This is really a case of type down/up casting. Not sure about .Net though.
- What is Foo suppose to be? Is it a helper class? If so I wouldn't implement to an interface, I would drop the constructor and make the private methods public. This way you might be able to use them directly and avoid the manual casting.
- Alternatively Java is an object oriented language and therefore if `helpIt` is behaviour of an `Animal` I would move the method into the Animal class and drop the helper class all together.